# Magento 2.3.0 TinyMCE removes anchor tag href suffix when used with {{store url=''}}

Tags: magento2, category, cms-block, tinymce

I am trying to add category link in the CMS block.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}test-collection.html">Test Collection</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I hide/show editor, it removes "test-collection.html" from the code. New output:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li><a href="{{store url=''}}">Test Collection</a></li>
</ul>
```

In previous versions, it was working fine. Help, please.

Comment: Have your resolved your query?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution for this

Go this file: `lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/html5-schema.js`

Replace this:

```
['a', 'href target rel media hreflang type charset name rev shape coords download', phrasingContent],
```

With this:

```
['a', 'href target rel media hreflang type charset name rev shape coords download', flowContent],
```

Good approach to override this file in your custom theme

The reason this fixes the issue is that the `flowContent` array includes block level tags and inline tags unlike the `phrasingContent` array which includes only inline elements.

The first element of this array is the a the tag we want to fix, the second array entry appears to be attributes allowed on a tags, and the third array entry (the one we care about) appears to be allowed children.

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/web/tiny_mce_4/tinymce.min.js

OR

If you check out to the TinyMCE 3 configuration archive above, there are some settings which would allow you to disable it, for example this one:

Reference: http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:verify_html

**I hope this will help**